# DataFrame constructor not properly called and RangeIndex object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas

```
monthly = data.BuyHold.diff().resample("M").sum
toHeatMap = pd.DataFrame(monthly)
toHeatMap["Year"] = toHeatMap.index.year
toHeatMap["Month"] = toHeatMap.index.month
Show = toHeatMap.groupby(by = ["Year", "Month"]).sum().unstack()
Show.columns = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-676-a1c93d6dd0d8> in <module>
      1 monthly = data.BuyHold.diff().resample("M").sum
----> 2 toHeatMap = pd.DataFrame(monthly)
      3 toHeatMap["Year"] = toHeatMap.index.year
      4 toHeatMap["Month"] = toHeatMap.index.month
      5 Show = toHeatMap.groupby(by = ["Year", "Month"]).sum().unstack()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    527         else:
    528             if index is None or columns is None:
--> 529                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    530 
    531             if not dtype:

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

The program says DataFrame constructor not properly called in the line 2. If I use "eval" it reports an error on line 3 that says "'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'month'".

Thank you !!

Comment: Post the full error with it's trace

Comment: Ok I added it thank you

Comment: Would you mind explaining _What you are trying to achieve with the code_
?

Comment: I wold create a matrix with Years and Months with the data in BuyHold inside "data" that is a Pandas Dataframe. I copy that from a book but I can't understand where is the error (I write the very same code).

Comment: `monthly = data.BuyHold.diff().resample("M").sum` is the function `Resample.sum` I believe you meant to call the function `monthly = data.BuyHold.diff().resample("M").sum()` to take the monthly sum. Notice the `()` after sum.

Comment: Thank you now it's ok !!